# > Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED Error while building react-native app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk

i'm running gradlew assemble command and i keep getting this error

```
> Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED
'[node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i'm getting this error even though i have node installed, here's Full output of error:

```
> Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED
'[node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createReleaseExpoManifest'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
920 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 903 up-to-date
```